# Why can't my javascript code in the head selection get an element?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a pi calculator in javascript for a long time now and I have finally finished. The problem is that my script in the head section:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', (function(){
    alert('Beginning…');
}), false);
```

And I have this in my body section:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Calculate!!"/>
```

But when I open the webpage, I get the following error: "null is not an object, evaluating document.getElementById("button").addEventListener"

Does anyone know why my code isn't functioning properly?

Thank you.

Comment: The element doesn't yet exist on the page. To avoid this, consider moving your `<script></script>` to the bottom of your body (i.e. `<script></script></body></html>`)

Comment: Either do a `window.onload = function()` or append it to after the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @pattmorter Before the closing `</body>` tag. Nothing should go after  `</body>` except `</html>`.

Comment: @War10ck Well, since it is in the head section of the page, javascript should be able to find the element.

Comment: @Progo Incorrect. Only if it is wrapped in an `onload` event. JavaScript is loaded and immediately parsed. This stops the loading/rendering of the HTML until the JavaScript parsing is complete. (i.e. the element ***will not*** be loaded on the page by the time the JavaScript parses)

Comment: @War10ck well i look like a fool now haha.... You're right, it isn't*valid HTML but it still *works*. Thank you for making me aware of the right way or I would have never noticed!

Comment: @pattmorter My apologies. I wasn't trying to cause any trouble. I'm sorry if it seemed like I did. It's interesting that it works. Browsers nowadays seem to be very forgiving. It can be both a blessing and a curse. That's really cool though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap it on a **window** `onload` event:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', (function(){
        alert('Beginning…');
    }), false);
};
```

or

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', (function(){
        alert('Beginning…');
    }), false);
});
```

or, if your script doesn't have to be in the **head,** put it after the element that has the id of **button.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cRX5L/)**

Comment: This definitely a possible solution, +1

Comment: You know, I can't help but wonder why this answer got 1 downvote recently.

Comment: @ManofSnow Yes, now I can, it said that I had to wait several minutes and by then I was asleep.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript gets executed ass soon as possible, so when it's in the head tag, the document hasn't fully loaded. you can have your code run when the document is ready by using the load even

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    /*your code here*/
});
```

I guess window is supposed to be the proper way to do it, even though one would think document.load would be there ("When the document loads, do this" instead of "when the window loads do this")
or run your code at the end of the body. You can still have all your methods in the head.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Wrap your code in a `window.onload` event.
2. Place your `<script></script>` at the bottom of the body right before `</body>`.