# I am encountering some errors while doing the JavaScript implementation on my little project, Calculator. Can you help me, guys?

Tags: javascript

**Here is the error message**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
```

**This is the code**

```js
let equal = document.querySelector(".btn-equal");
equal.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (screen.value === "") {
    screen.value = "";
  } else {
    let answer = eval(screen.value);
    screen.value = answer;
  }
});
```

**Btw, I am a beginner on coding**
**I hope that I can make it work**
**Thank you**

Comment: Please search for answer to your question before posting. Several come up just when searching you error message. In fact, I saw a very, very similar question quite recently (asking for help on all kinds of things for a calculator, including this issue).

Comment: Two simple questions with simple answers: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') when adding functionality to modal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71961602/15261914) and [Why can't my javascript code in the head selection get an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21009922/15261914). While the sole answer here is reasonable, I'm going to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't my javascript code in the head selection get an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21009922/why-cant-my-javascript-code-in-the-head-selection-get-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `document.querySelector('.btn-equal');` not finding any elements, which means that `equal` is null, and so `equal.addEventListener()` is calling a method on an object that doesn't exist.

Most likely you are either calling `document.querySelector()` before the document has finished loading, or the element you want to select is not being identified properly. To debug this issue you can run `console.log(document.querySelector('.some-other-element'))` and see if you are able to fetch any parts of the page or not.